# Adding new button with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I am trying to create  a button ,when user write something on the textbox.I can create a new

button using jQuery when user click the button , but how can I create immediately new button

when user enter some value using JQuery?

thanks...

Comment: look at the keyup/change event

Comment: Show us what you've got so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you keep getting/reading the value that the user enters, then check if it matches your target word(s)

Code similar to this:

```
$("#myTextField").on("keyup change ",  function () {
  //Now you want to compare your code here
  var text = $(this).val();
  if(text.indexOf("YES") > -1 )// -1 is the index of the string, -1 means it doesn't exist. 0 means it's the first occurrence in the string. 1 means it's at index 1. 
  {
    //Create your button here.     
  }
})
```

Comment: @user3160355 
Glad to help. If this answer gives what you need, then kindly up-vote it and mark it as a correct answer so others can benefit from it as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

See something like [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).